# MacOS swiftUI using NavigationStack toolbar button not showing in MenuBarExtra app

Tags: macos, swiftui, menubar

I'm creating a menubar only application to scratch an itch of mine and I'm running into an issue using navigation stack and the toolbar to add a "add" button.

```
    var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading){

        NavigationStack{
            
            List(projects){ project in
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ProjectDetailView(project: project)){
                    Text(project.name)
                }
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Projects")
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation, content: {   Button(
                    action: {AddProject()},
                    label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus").imageScale(.large)
                        
                    }
                )
                }
                )

                
            }
            }
            
    }.frame(width: 400,height:600)

}
```

I tried using it outside the VStack as well with same result.

The navigation title and button show up fine in preview mode. But when I run the application only the title shows up. The button is not there. Also note if I click on a navigation link the toolbar has the back button.

here is a screenshot. [image: Screenshot]

Wondering if this is a bug or anyone come across this situation?

Comment: Please also post your app struct.

Comment: I can confirm the toolbar button is not there when used inside a `MenuBarExtra` (macOS 13.6.1, Xcode 15). Seems fine & I see the plus button when used inside a `Window` or `WindowGroup`.